# Invalid read of size 1

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind, strtok, atoi

I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to run my program. After using valgrind these were my errors:

```
==32592== Invalid read of size 1
==32592==    at 0x3753637172: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:298)
==32592==    by 0x3753633F1F: atoi (atoi.c:28)
==32592==    by 0x400B12: main (in /some/directory)
==32592==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

this is the loop which my problem definitely exists, but I cannot find where:

```
while( fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL ) {
        ++linenum;
        token = strtok(line, " \n");
        if ( linenum == 1 ) {
            n = atoi(token);
            G = newGraph(n);
        }else {
            x = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            y = atoi(token);
            if( x != 0 ) {
                addArc(G, x, y);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is an example of a text file I will be reading in:

```
9
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 5
5 4
4 3
5 6
6 8
7 6
8 7
8 9
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
2 4
2 5
2 6
2 7
2 8
2 9
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 9
4 6
4 7
4 8
4 9
5 7
5 8
5 9
6 9
7 9
9 9
0 0
```

Comment: The example text file is opened in binary mode? Does it have embedded `'\r'` from Windows?

Comment: `linenum` Do you initialized to 0?

Answer (score 2):

`strtok()` could very well return `NULL`, which is not a good idea to pass to `atoi()`.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok()` can return `NULL` so check value of `token` before using it.

```
token = strtok(line, " \n");
if(token != NULLL)
{
        if ( linenum == 1 ) {
            n = atoi(token);
            G = newGraph(n);
        }else {
            x = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            if(token != NULL)
                y = atoi(token);
            if( x != 0 ) {
                addArc(G, x, y);
            }
  }
```

Comment: Yes this is correct. After using gdb, I figured out that the error comes at:
y = atoi(token);

which probably meant that it reached the end of the text file